# Ordering in Linq to Entities Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table in SQL Server that has the following columns

- ID        (Identity/Primary Key)
- DestinationID    (Foreign key)
- Date      (Date Field)
- Time      (Time Field)
- DayOfWeek (Char(3) Field) i.e. "MON","TUE" etc..

I want to order the data by Date and Time, then by DayOfWeek and Time. So all the records with dates appear at the top, and ordered by time, then the DayOfWeek order by time.

I have tried several ways but just cant get my head around it, I have the following code

```
    var qry = ctx.DestinationTimings.Where(x => x.DestinationID == this.ID)
                     .OrderBy(t => t.Date).ThenBy(t => t.Date != null)
                     .ThenBy(t => SqlFunctions.CharIndex(t.DayOfWeek + ",", "MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN"))
                     .ThenBy(t => t.Time);
```

Comment: use Select method(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

Comment: I did look into the select method, but I think it would have been a little over the top, I had an incline it would be something simple

Comment: @Kiquenet `SqlFunctions.CharIndex` Will return the position of the value found in another expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.charindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `Date` is nullable you could do something like this:

```
var qry = ctx.DestinationTimings.Where(x => x.DestinationID == this.ID)
                 .OrderBy(t => t.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
                 .ThenBy(t => SqlFunctions.CharIndex(t.DayOfWeek + ",", "MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN"))
                 .ThenBy(t => t.Time);
```