# How can I generate running numbers for days?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of employees with days. I am using C# to generate running numbers in the days column as shown in the image below.
I have tried the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422849/implement-dense-rank-with-linq) and was able to generate a dense rank for each group.
I am not able to generate a running number for the rest of the items in the list.

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Comment: What does the input list look like.   It looks like you are creating a pivot table.  So first step is to get the max number of days.  Then create a table with the number of columns 3 (empnumber, empName, Number of days) + max number of days.  Then fill in table.  So if you have max number of days = 10 the number of columns is 13.

Comment: What data type do you expect the result to use?

Answer (score 1):

Since I like LINQ :)

Using my simplest implementation of the APL Scan operator for `IEnumerable` (which is like `Aggregate` but returns the intermediate results):

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // Explicit seed value
    // TRes combineFn(TRes PrevResult, T CurValue)
    public static IEnumerable<TRes> Scan<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TRes seed, Func<TRes, T, TRes> combineFn) {
        foreach (var s in src) {
            seed = combineFn(seed, s);
            yield return seed;
        }
    }    
}
```

And a simple class the increments each time it is read:

```
public class GeneratorInt {
    int curValue = 1;

    public int Value {
        get {
            return curValue++;
        }
    }
}
```

You can compute the answer (using `null` for the empty boxes):

```
var ans = src.Scan(new {
                        EmpNumber = 0,
                        EmpName = "",
                        NumberOfDays = 0,
                        Days1 = (GeneratorInt)null,
                        Days2 = (GeneratorInt)null,
                        Days3 = (GeneratorInt)null,
                        Days4 = (GeneratorInt)null,
                        Days5 = (GeneratorInt)null
                   },
                   (acc, r) => new {
                        r.EmpNumber,
                        r.EmpName,
                        r.NumberOfDays,
                        Days1 = r.NumberOfDays >= 1 ? (acc.Days1 ?? new GeneratorInt()) : null,
                        Days2 = r.NumberOfDays >= 2 ? (acc.Days2 ?? new GeneratorInt()) : null,
                        Days3 = r.NumberOfDays >= 3 ? (acc.Days3 ?? new GeneratorInt()) : null,
                        Days4 = r.NumberOfDays >= 4 ? (acc.Days4 ?? new GeneratorInt()) : null,
                        Days5 = r.NumberOfDays >= 5 ? (acc.Days5 ?? new GeneratorInt()) : null,
                   }
             )
             .Select(a => new {
                a.EmpNumber,
                a.EmpName,
                a.NumberOfDays,
                Days1 = a.Days1?.Value,
                Days2 = a.Days2?.Value,
                Days3 = a.Days3?.Value,
                Days4 = a.Days4?.Value,
                Days5 = a.Days5?.Value,
             })
             .ToList();
```

If you need to handle differing potential number of `Days`# fields, then you have to decide how you want to handle them - using one field of type `List<int>` or of type `IEnumerable<int>`, or using a `DataTable` and create columns dynamically?